# How can I get a vector inside a square as a function of two others?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

The problem is as follows:

The figure from below represents three vectors $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ and
$\vec{x}$. Find $\vec{x}$ as a function of a linear combination of the

> other two. Assume the figure is a square.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&3\vec{u}-2\vec{v}\\
2.&4\vec{u}-3\vec{v}\\
3.&\frac{3\vec{u}+2\vec{v}}{4}\\
4.&\frac{2\vec{u}+3\vec{v}}{4}\\
5.&\frac{3\vec{u}+2\vec{v}}{5}\\
\end{array}$

How exactly should this problem should be approached?. I attempted different ways to accomodate the vectors but I have ran out of ideas.

From what I can see, it seems that it is intended to assume that $M$ and $N$ are midpoints. Although it has not been indicated otherwise.

But if that were the case, I can see that the angle which vector $\vec{v}$ makes with the horizontal, assuming the horizontal is the bottom edge of the square, would be $\frac{53^\circ}{2}$ as it is in a proportion of $2:1$ ratio. But, other than that I don't know what else can be done to simplify or solve this thing.

Can someone help me here please?.  because I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I skip writing the vector symbols to type it faster.

A possible way is using a [secant-tangent relation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleTangentLine.html).

For simplicity let's set the side length of the square to $1$. So you have

$$v = OR + \frac 12 u \text{ and } OM = u + \frac 12 OR$$
So, you get
$$OM = \frac 12 v+\frac 34 u$$

Now, $x = t\cdot OM \Rightarrow t = \frac{|x|}{|OM|}$. Using above mentioned secant-tangent relation, you get

$$|PM|^2=\frac 14 = (|OM|-|x|)|OM|$$

Pythagoras gives $|OM| = \frac{\sqrt 5}{2}$ and solving for $|x|$ gives $|x| = \frac 2{\sqrt 5}$. Hence,

$$x = \frac{|x|}{|OM|}\left(\frac 12 v+\frac 34 u\right) = \frac 45\left(\frac 12 v+\frac 34 u\right)=\boxed{\frac{2v+3u}5}$$

Comment: I'm stuck on why $x=t\cdot OM$? Where did you get this equation?. Are you referring to the unitary vector? Or is it just that you are intending to get the scalar?. What's its justification?. I'm confused with this part. The rest was like domino tiles, in other words I get the idea. In order to use the tangent secant identity you must assume the lenght of the square is $1$ thus $PM=\frac{1}{2}$ which means that you are assuming that those $M$ and $N$ are acting as midpoints. But can you please explain my doubt?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell : Concerning your first question: According to your picture $x$ is a shortened version of $OM$. So, $x$ must be a scalar multiple of $OM$. And I just guessed from the picture that $M$ and $N$ are the midpoints of the sides. Otherwise I couldn't see a way to set up meaningful equations for the vectors without several unknown parameters.

Comment: I see, so anytime when I see a vector which has a little segment next to it (as in this case) I could assume that the greater vector can be expressed as an scalar times the little vector, am I right with this?. You used tangent secant identity for this, but it could had been used similarity of triangles, is this right?. But I believe for the way how it was presented a tangent secant approach was maybe intended. By the way I like your answer is very neat.